# routing of static pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm new to PHP and CodeIgniter, and I'm having trouble setting up the routing of static pages in my CodeIgniter app.

I have the `ciblog/pages/views/about` and it works.
I want to change it into `ciblog/about`.
I already have in the routes.php the `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`
and it doesn't work it says in the browser:

> page not found..

Please please help me I want to learn how to set up a static page....

Here is the code in the routes.php

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


    $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
    ?>
```

This is in my controller

```
    <?php
        class Pages extends CI_Controller{
            public function views($page = 'home'){
                if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                    show_404();

                                                                    }
                $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
                                                }


                                        }


?>
```

here is in the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please show your actual Controller ( at the moment its a direct copy of your routes.php ) And Please show your htaccess file. Update your question to show those please.

Comment: my actual controller is in the post this is my first controller 

I update my post to show the .htaccess

Please Please help me....   Thank you

Comment: Well what you have shown as your controller is not a controller. It's still just a copy of your routes.php file. So..............

Comment: Ooops... Sorry my bad I thought it was my controller I updated my post

Comment: Please help im still stuck here

Comment: @itchigokuraski Now I can see your actual controller, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work, If your Controller is along the lines of...
This is the simplest, bare bones option.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function view($page) {
        $this->load->view($page);
    }
}
```

Where the view method accepts a parameter.

Of course you would need to check that the view file exists etc and take the appropriate action.

**Update:**
Now that you have shown your Controller, I can see you are referring to view in your routes BUT you Controller method is called views ( with an added s).

They have to be the same.

So the quickest way to make them the same is to change

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

to ( By adding an s to views so its the same as the controller method )

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/views/$1';
```

OR you can simply change the method name from views to view.

Your choice!

Comment: is there any other way wherein the url browser has the "ciblog/about"?

Comment: Is there any other way to remove the class name and the function name in the url browser??

Comment: Well you have a working answer. This requires that you have your "static" pages in your views folder.... There are other ways to call an about.php outside of CI directly. But do you want to do that?

Comment: Ooooooh..  It works thank you very much now.....  Thank you.. Thank you.... Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "about" page is to be served by the view method of the pages controller,

```
$route['about'] = 'pages/view/about';
```